# PHP LDAP connection authenticates without DN information

Tags: php, binding, active-directory, ldap, windows-server

It is the first time I am working with PHP 5 LDAP library and I am a bit confused. I would be very happy if anyone could give me some clarifications on the following:

**First of all let me give my configurations:**

**LDAP server:** Windows Server 2013 Active Directory

**Hostname:** winad

**Domain:** domain.local

**IP:** 1.1.1.1 (for the sake of explaining)

**Windows Account used for binding:** Administrator

Ping hostname from dev machine works

Ping ip from dev machine works

Ping winad.domain.local from dev machine fails

**Development Environment:** Windows 8 Professional with WAMP

**PHP:** 5.3.13

PHP LDAP Module loaded and working

Apache LDAP module not loaded

**Scenario:**

I am trying to authenticate a user against the Windows AD with the administrator account for a start. Here is a sample of my code:

I will be using these variables in the various scenarios below:

```
$hostname = "winad";
$dnex= "uid=Administrator, ou=Users, dc=domain, dc=local";
```

Code that works:

```
$conn = ldap_connect($hostname);
$bind = ldap_bind($conn, "DOMAIN\Administrator", "password");
```

Code that fails:

```
$conn = ldap_connect($hostname);
$bind = ldap_bind($conn, $dnex, "password");
```

Error: Invalid credentials

Now my question is why does it fails when I specify a dn?

Let say I have location1.domain.local and location2.domain.local and I want to bind only with location2, it does not seem possible without specifying the dn.

Can somebody show the right way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more search I found the following post:

[PHP LDAP Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232950/php-ldap-connection?rq=1)

The response from AlexC answered my question correctly.

Hope this is helpful.