# PHP page level authentication

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

What is the best approach if I've to use an LDAP authentication - which isn't in my control - but after it's successful I'd like to make some pages available to a set of users? Do I have to store the selected users data somewhere?

Comment: How about showing what you've tried first

Comment: I didn't jump into testing various methods. I don't need some raw code to copy it into. Just looking for expert opinion where to start so I don't need to fail, or later modify the whole authenticating process.

Comment: SO isn't for broad questions like that, tho. Here's an example of a good LDAP question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232950/php-ldap-connection

Comment: Okay, noted. Trying elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give concrete advise whithout knowing what you already tried and did. So it's a fairly broad question I can't give a concrete answer to.

But I can give you some hints as to where to look for more information:

- You will need to do authentication against LDAP. There are a lot of examples around on the web.Which one you use depends on whether you are using an framework or want to solve it with plain old PHP. One - but by far not the only - example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592).
- You will need some form of authorization whether the logging in user is allowed to see those pages cor not. You can euther do that by storing a lit of usernames that are allowed to see the pages or by using a certain LDAP-group whose users are allowed see the pages.
- Whether you store the user-informations persistent in a database or in the session depends on the use-case. I wouldn't store the user-information persistently but simply in the users session after the user logs in. But as I said, that depends on the use-case.

I hope that helps somehow.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you and sorry for being absent, but an another project took over. At the moment I solely depend on the LDAP registered informations and if its needed in the future I'll check on the options.

Comment: If you are looking for general advise. you might want to have a look at http://rawgit.com/heiglandreas/slidedeck/master/Directory_Authentication_with_LDAP/20150813%20-%20zurichphp/index_online.html#/ ;)

Comment: The "problem" is that I'm developing a small frontend site for a few hundred workers in a larger company and I've to use the system already in place. The only thing they can help me to create new "groups" if there's something specific set of users, but at the moment there are already too many of these (I'm in 27) so...
Nevertheless I'm eager to learn always and will check the slides.
Thank you!